# How to select two random players from a List and then display them separately in the UI in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List of players:

```
final List<String> _players = [];
```

which I populate from the UI using:

```
  addPlayerToList() {
    if (playerNameController.text.isNotEmpty && _players.length < 3) {
      setState(() {
        _players.add(playerNameController.text);
      });
    }
  }
```

from which I want to pick random two players:

```
var randomPair = '';

generatePair<T>(List<T> players, int count) {
  randomPair = (players.toList()..shuffle()).take(count).toString();
}
```

So far so good, but the problems start when I'm trying to split the result of the above operation which is `(Player1, Player4)` into two separate strings in order to display them nicely in the UI i.e. modal with some flashy `Player1 vs. Player2`:

```
getNames() {
  var playerNames = randomPair.split(',');
  for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
    playerNames.add(playerNames[i]);
  }
  return playerNames;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make `randomPair` a `List<String>` and then do: `randomPair = (players.toList()..shuffle()).take(count).toList();`. You then have a list which contains your two player names without the need to manually splitting a String afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating a String, which contains the pair, for then split the string, we should instead just write the code so it returns a list with two random selected players.

So something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> players = ['Player A', 'Player B', 'Player C', 'Player D'];
  List<String> selectedPlayers = selectRandomAmount(players, 2);
  print(selectedPlayers); // [Player C, Player A]
}

List<T> selectRandomAmount<T>(List<T> players, int count) =>
    [...(players.toList()..shuffle()).take(count)];
```